# How to append Audio Strips from One Blender VSE to another Blender VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am having a Blender file with an image strip and four nos. of audio strips (as shown in ‘A’, at the attached Screenshot). I would like to place all of the audio strips at the exact frames as ‘A’, at a fresh VSE of a different blender file (in ‘B’, at the attached Screenshot).
2.  The main reason is that in the Blender file ‘A’, the original Animation was done and due the size of the Blender file (may be), the image quality of the appended image strips appears different from the original rendered image. However, when the rendered image is appended in a fresh blender file, the original image quality can be retrieved but if I do so, the all audio strips are required to be placed manually, since, I don’t know how to bring all the image strips from one Blender VSE to another Blender VSE.
3.  This is also a general query because in this short duration and for four nos. of audio strips, this might not be a tedious process if I do manually, but for a large blender files where there are many nos. of audio files, a solution is required as to how audio strips can be appended in a fresh Blender file at the exact frame.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Well, I guess the easiest thing would be to simply change the _Color Management_ in A, because I suspect that is what is making your image sequence look different. If you rendered it with let's say _Filmic_ and _High Contrast_ for example and saved the images like that, adding them in the image sequencer would now apply those view transforms a second time on the images. Set _Color Management_ > _View Transform_ to _Standard_, _Look_ to _None_, _Exposure_ to 0 and _Gamma_ to 1 and see if the image sequence still looks wrong.

Comment: Firstly, Thanks for your reply. Your answer developed the quality of the image from its initial appearance. However, the original quality could not be retrieved. a Google drive link is shared here for your observation, what it looks now vs. the original rendered image quality.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/15zTa7yDoCwn2iS-RTrxSqrNuwMBZwFdU/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Honestly, the comparison is already visible in the question - just from seeing two different appearances of an image it is hard to examine why they differ, because they shouldn't so there must be a reason behind this. For copying the audio strips from A to B there is no option to do that.

Answer (score 1):

In my example I suppose that the first audio strip starts at frame 10:

Select all audio strips that have to be copied, press Ctrl C.

Open the new file, set the VSE time cursor to frame 10, press Ctrl V.